# How to get the Average of a Row After Getting Count?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to use an aggregate function to get the average(count( of a row in SQL Server. However, I continue to get this message:

> "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

In the first picture is the table, in the second picture is the table with the counts for each officer_id, I am trying to find the average amount of calls per officer and cannot seem to find the right SQL query to do it.

The query I thought may work is:

```
SELECT AVG(COUNT(officer_id))
FROM crime_officers
ORDER BY officer_id;
```

But this is where I get the aggregate error. Does anyone have any recommendations?

[UPDATED table with this query
SELECT officer_id, COUNT(crime_id)
FROM crime_officers
GROUP BY officer_id;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuLnA.png)

[Original table: crime_officers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bowmK.png)

Comment: It doesn't make sense logically to nest aggregate functions which is why it fails. What are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Images of technical information like sample data, results, or code, instead of **formatted text**, is the fastest way I've seen here to have your question downvoted and then closed or ignored with no answer.

Comment: What do you expect `AVG(COUNT(officer_id))` to return? The average of a single value is the single value. Having an `ORDER BY` makes little sense either. With a single value it doesn't matter what "order* you it in it's the same order; it's one value, it is the first and last value.

Comment: If you want the average number of calls per officer, then you want the total number of calls divided by the number of distinct officers. If you want the total number of calls for each officer then you just want a count of the calls grouped by officer. You seem to be merging these two distinct ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this query provides the average number of crimes per officer. A single value, which is equal to the total number of crimes divided between all officers.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)*1.0/COUNT(distinct officer_id) as 'Average Crimes per Officer'
FROM crime_officers;
```

Comment: Thank you Sebastian, this resolved the issue, I spent too much time trying to find a solution while using the AVG() aggregate when really I should have thought of other potential solutions. Thanks again, this resolved the issue!!!

Comment: I would make a small suggestion. Multiply either the top or the bottom count by 1.0, as coded here this will do integer division which will always return an integer.

Comment: Good thinking @SeanLange

Comment: `COUNT(officer_id)` is the same as `COUNT(*)` also `COUNT(distinct(officer_id))` is weird because `distinct` isn't a function and doesn't need brackets